# Copying the selected files to a different directory

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

I have the following command which returns the files that are modified on that day.

```
for /F "tokens=2" %i in ('date /t') do dir /T:C | findstr /C:%i /B
```

I would need to know how to copy these selected file from the current directory to a new directory? Can this be achieved with copy command?

```
copy for /F "tokens=2" %i in ('date /t') do dir /T:C | findstr /C:%i /B "D:Test\"
```

No errors and script doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Without re-writing any of your existing code to find today's files, you can utilize `forfiles`

```
for /F "tokens=2" %i in ('date /t') do forfiles /D +%i /C "cmd /c copy @path <destination_path>"
```